# I'm running a nightly build, will apt-get upgrade keep me current?

Tags: updates, daily-build

I'm trying out the xenial nightly, and I'm wondering if I have to download a new nightly once in a while to keep up to date, or if running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will keep me current.

Answer (score 2):

To stay current, you must update and then dist-upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will allow you to update all packages, possibly installing new ones and removing obsolete ones, for the currently installed release of Ubuntu.

If you already have the latest installed version of Ubuntu and would like to directly upgrade to the development release instead of installing nightlies, you can use:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Which will check if a development release is available, and ask if you'd like to upgrade to it. Going back is significantly harder if at all possible, so take a backup if you'd like that option.